# .onAppear vs init on @main and child views in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, initialization, onappear

I'm seeking clarity on the reasonings - if any known - why the order of initialisation and view modifiers occurs.

I couldn't find any documentation on this but hoping someone might know why.

I have the following example code:

```swift
@main
struct TestApp: App {
  init() { print("@main: init" }
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
        .onAppear { let _ = print("@main: onAppear" }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {}
      .onAppear { let _ = print("ContentView: onAppear" }
  }
}
```

When this runs, the console outputs the following:

```
@main - init
ContentView - onAppear
@main - onAppear
```

Does anyone know why or any reasoning why the order would be `init`, child view `.onAppear`, then main `.onAppear`?

I guess in my mind the order would be initialising all of the `@main` including the modifiers before any of the child views - but maybe there is a proper reason for the current order.

Comment: Probably building the elements of a View before the View itself

Comment: This thread could be related to your question: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `onAppear` says:

> The exact moment that SwiftUI calls this method depends on the specific view type that you apply it to, but the action closure completes before the first rendered frame appears.

So depending on the type of view, `onAppear` could totally be called in any order, as long as it is "before the first rendered frame appears".

Here is a possible explanation for your particular example.

If you just "flatten" `ContentView`, you end up with a `VStack` with 2 `onAppear`s:

```
VStack {}
    // 1
    .onAppear { let _ = print("ContentView: onAppear" }
    // 2
    .onAppear { let _ = print("@main: onAppear" }
```

Each `onAppear` is modifying everything "above" it. "@main: onAppear" is printed when everything above `// 2` has "appeared". That means that the `VStack` must have already appeared. Therefore, "@main: onAppear" is printed after "ContentView: onAppear".

And of course, "@main: init" is the first thing being printed, because without creating an instance of `TestApp`, SwiftUI cannot call the getter of `body`, and hence cannot know anything about what views you have.

From my experiments, most SwiftUI "containers" have their `onAppear` called first, before the `onAppear` of the views in them.

```
VStack {
    Text("Foo")
        .id("Foo")
        .onAppear {
            print("1")
        }
    
    Text("Foo")
        .onAppear {
            print("2")
        }
}
.onAppear {
    print("3")
}

// prints in the order of 3 2 1
```

This aligns with your expectation, if I understand correctly. The `VStack` can appear first, without any subviews, then the subviews appear. Your `ContentView` cannot do something similar - it is literally just a wrapper around a single `VStack`.